# How would you convert a one column series to a one row series with a header?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas and I would like to convert a series like this:

```
        RT_mean
   0     27
   1     32
   2     10
   3     9
   .
   .
   .   
   190   89
   191   6
```

to a one row dataframe with a header like this:

```
       RT_mean1  RT_mean2  RT_mean3  RT_mean4 ... RT_mean189 RT_mean190
   0      27        32        10        9     ...     89          6
```

I tried doing `series.transpose()` but that doesn't work on series.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try something silly like `df.set_index(df.index.map('RT_mean{}'.format)).rename({'RT_mean':0},axis=1).T`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yet another approach

```
pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().T).add_prefix('RT_mean')

   RT_mean0  RT_mean1  RT_mean2  RT_mean3  RT_mean4  RT_mean5
0        27        32        10         9        89         6
```

To maximize generality, we can `add_prefix` with the value of the first column name

```
pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().T).add_prefix(df.columns[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one which requires recreating your DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame([df['RT_mean'].tolist()], columns=df.index.map('RT_mean{}'.format))

   RT_mean0  RT_mean1  RT_mean2  RT_mean3
0        27        32        10         9
```

---

Another which involves `set_index` and `transpose`:

```
df.set_index(df.index.map('RT_mean{}'.format)).reset_index(drop=True).T

   RT_mean0  RT_mean1  RT_mean2  RT_mean3
0        27        32        10         9
```

Or `transpose` and `set_axis`:

```
(df.T
   .set_axis(df.index.map('RT_mean{}'.format), axis=1, inplace=False)
   .reset_index(drop=True))

   RT_mean0  RT_mean1  RT_mean2  RT_mean3
0        27        32        10         9
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the series in the DataFrame constructor before using `transpose`.

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(pd.np.random.randint(0,100, size=50))
pd.DataFrame(s).T.rename(columns={x: 'RT_mean{}'.format(x) for x in s.index})
# returns:
  RT_mean0  RT_mean1  RT_mean2  RT_mean3  RT_mean4  RT_mean5  RT_mean6  \
0       74        96        31         1        36        98        79
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `pd.Series` into a `pd.DataFrame` and then transpose it:   `y = pd.DataFrame(x).transpose()`